# Matlab. Replace missed values with an avg

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

**Question**

How to replace missed columns values with an average value for string (the most occurring class) and number columns?

Example of data was taken from:

[UCI ML Repo. Iris](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris)

For example, replace `NaN` with *'Iris-setosa'*

[image]

**Code I have**

It replaces only values, but how to replace strings too.

```
function dataWithReplaced = replaceNaNWithAvg(data)

dataWithReplaced = [ ];

averagePerCol = table2array(varfun(@nanmean, data(: , 1:4)));

for i = 1:4

    dataColumn = table2array(data( : , i));
    dataColumn(isnan(dataColumn)) = averagePerCol(1, i);

    dataWithReplaced = [dataWithReplaced dataColumn];

end

end
```

I'm a new in MATlab, so many things are not obvious for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution solves the problem:

- Convert last table column to cell array (cell array is required for holding strings with different lengths).
- [Remove all NaN elements from cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/314852) (NaN elements disrupt the next section).
- [Find most repeated string in cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7973-how-to-find-out-which-item-is-mode-of-cell-array).
- Find all indeces of NaN elements in stringColumn (I used `cellfun` based on previous section).
- Rplace elements in indeces found, with most common string.

Since you are new to Matlab, my solution is going to look extremely complicated for you (it looks complicated for me).
There might be a simpler solution, that I could't find...

See the following code sample:

```
%Create data table for the example.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
VarName1 = [4.9; 7.3; 6.7; 7.2; 6.5; 6.4; 6.8; 5.7; 5.8; 6.4; 6.5];
VarName2 = [2.5; 2.9; 2.5; 3.6; 3.2; 2.7; 3.0; 2.5; 2.8; 3.2; 3.0];
VarName3 = [4.5; 6.3; 5.8; 6.1; 5.1; 5.3; 5.5; 5.0; 5.1; 5.3; 5.5];
VarName4 = [1.7; 1.8; 1.8; 2.5; 2.0; 1.9; 2.1; 2.0; 2.4; 2.3; 1.8];
VarName5 = {NaN; 'aa'; 'aa'; 'bbb'; NaN; 'ccc'; 'ccc'; 'ccc'; 'ccc'; 'dddd'; 'dddd'};
data = table(VarName1, VarName2, VarName3, VarName4, VarName5);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Convert last table column to cell array.
stringColumn = table2cell(data(:, 5));

%Remove all NaN elements from cell array
%Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/314852
x = stringColumn(cell2mat(cellfun(@ischar,stringColumn,'UniformOutput',0)));

%Find most repeated string in cell array:
%Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7973-how-to-find-out-which-item-is-mode-of-cell-array
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
y = unique(x);
n = zeros(length(y), 1);
for iy = 1:length(y)
    n(iy) = length(find(strcmp(y{iy}, x)));
end
[~, itemp] = max(n);
commonStr = y(itemp);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Find all indeces of NaN elements in stringColumn.
nanIdx = find(cell2mat(cellfun(@ischar,stringColumn,'UniformOutput',0)) == 0);

%Rplace elements with NaN values with commonStr.
stringColumn(nanIdx) = commonStr;

%Replace last column of original table
data(:, 5) = stringColumn;
```

Comment: Thank you. I get it. I'm new in MATlab, but not in coding)