# MATLAB The function isnan is undefined for input arguments of type 'dataset'

Tags: matlab, dataset, nan

I have a dataset a little big (48000*53) and I'm trying to find the multivariate outliers on it. 
However each time I try a function such as trimmean(), leverage() I got the same error. 
My dataset is supposed to be clean of NaN value but I still tried to run the code `D(find(sum(isnan(D),2)==0),:);` and `D(any(isnan(D),2), :)=[];` but I got the same error....

Answer (score 0):

The following example removes all rows contains NaN elements from dataset.

The example is based on the following post: [Matlab. Replace missed values with an avg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073655/matlab-replace-missed-values-with-an-avg/40075788#40075788)

- Convert dataset to cell array.
- Find all indexes of NaN elements within cell array.
- Find indexes of rows with NaN elements.
- Keep only rows without NaN elements within cell array.
- Convert cell array back to dataset.

Check the following code sample:

```
%Create dataset for the example.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
VarName1 = [4; NaN; 6; 7; 6; 6; 6; 5; 5; 6; 6];
VarName2 = [2; 2; 2; 3; 3; 2; NaN; 2; 2; NaN; 3];
VarName3 = {'aa'; 'aa'; 'aa'; 'bbb'; 'bbb'; 'ccc'; 'ccc'; 'ccc'; 'ccc'; 'dddd'; 'dddd'};
D = dataset(VarName1, VarName2, VarName3);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Convert dataset to cell array.
C = dataset2cell(D);

%Find all indexes of NaN elements (use anonymous function).
nanIdx = cellfun(@(x)(any(isnan(x))), C);

%Find indexes of rows with NaN elements
nanRows = any(nanIdx,2);

%Keep only rows without NaN elements.
C = C(~nanRows, :);

D = cell2dataset(C);
```